# System.Net.Sockets Assembly not available in Xamarin

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, xamarin

Hey guys I'm working on a c# tcp listener. I am coming back to c# after a year or so but I have been working with java fluently (All i'm saying is you don't have to dumb it down too much). Anyway I can't seem to find where to import System.Net.Sockets! I have clicked the "references" tab but only have a System.Net assembly. Any help will do and I'm sure its just me being stupid xD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add System.Dll. Further information you can read from here.

[Assemblies Xamarin](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/under_the_hood/assemblies/)