# Using Windows.Networking.Sockets in Xamarin for Windows Phone

Tags: sockets, xamarin, windows-phone-8.1, cross-platform, tcpclient

I use `System.Net.Sockets` for `TCP/IP Client` in my cross-platform application. I have SharedProject where I have class responsible for connecting/receiving data. I can run app in `Android`, but I see that the `System.Net.Sockets` is not avaiable in `Windows Phone 8.1`. I read that to work with `Windows Phone` i can use `Windows.Networking.Sockets`, but when I add u`sing Windows.Networking.Sockets` in my class in `Shared Project` I get error:

> The type or namespace name 'Windows' could not be found

My question is how can I use `System.Net.Sockets` or `Windows.Networking.Sockets` with `Windows Phone 8.1` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I resolved my problem by enter to Shared Class Library, next I double click on .NET and from left side I select Windows and click button 'Add to References in Selected Project in Solution Explorer'  which is near search bar.

Answer (score 1):

According to this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23118059/system-net-sockets-assembly-not-available-in-xamarin), you need to add `System.Dll` to your project in order to use `System.Net.Sockets`.

Or you can also give a try to this [Sockets Plugin for Xamarin](https://www.nuget.org/packages/rda.SocketsForPCL/)

Comment: Now I have problem with Background Worker in PLC I add using System.ComponentModel; but i still get error.